# Browser debugger not working with Webpack 2 and webpack-dev-server

Tags: debugging, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I've spent last few hours to set up a new project utilizing Webpack 2 and Babel 6.

The problem I have is non working debugger (any browser). Breakpoints are simply ignored. Using `debugger;` works fine but browser does not breaks execution exactly in that line.

`webpack.config.js:`

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader"
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
};
```

`.babel.rc:`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "latest"
  ]
}
```

I'm running the whole thing with `webpack-dev-server -d`

Answer (score 0):

**devtool: "source-map",** option in webpack config should solve your problem.

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.jsx'],
output: {
    filename: 'js/bundle.[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/'
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
        config: path.join(__dirname, `config/${env}.configuration.js`)
    }
},
**devtool: "source-map",**
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: 'jQuery'
                }
            ]
        },
```